# how to handle multiple routes that match the same path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path="cheese">
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path=":category">
          <Route index element={<Article />} />
          <Route path=":id">
            <Route index element={<Article />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Article />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Article />} />t
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

In the above, if the path of the url is `/cheese/12345`, it is the second router that is matched, hence the element `<Article />` is returned.

How to correct this?

I am using React Router v6

Comment: That is exactly how route matching works, why are you expecting some other behavior? Or rather, what exactly are you wanting to happen here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router-dom@6` routes always exactly match paths, `"/cheese/12345"` is exactly matched by the very general `"/:category/:id"` route path rather than the specific `"/cheese"` path.

The nested `<Route path="*" element={<Home />} />` under the parent `"/cheese"` route should also be matched by `"/cheese/12345"`.

If you want to de-duplicate the `Home` component on two routes and for the first route to match `"/cheese"` and also any "sub-route"/descendent path then it should have a wildcard `"*"` matcher appended to the path.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/cheese/*" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Article />} />
</Routes>
```

If you would like to also capture any cheese id values then you can specify an optional path param (*only RRDv6.5+*).

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/cheese/:id?" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Article />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-handle-multiple-routes-that-match-the-same-path]

Comment: I made an edit. The first Route actually does have a sub Route with a wildcard

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture That's not a sub-route, that's a nested route, they aren't *quite* the same thing. Let me do a test and verify.

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture Well, that nested route should also work.

Comment: I doesn't work for me. I think the `:anything` has a higher priority than `"*"`

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture Yes,  I believe named parameters, i.e. `:anything`, will be awarded more specificity than `"*"`. Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? I've added a working codesandbox link in my answer.

Comment: I have modified the example in https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-handle-multiple-routes-that-match-the-same-path-forked-xjrwvk?file=/src/App.js to reproduce my error

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture In your sandbox example it seems `"/:category/:id"` has higher specificity than `"*"` as a nested route of `"/cheese"` with the way you've broken the routes down with regards to path `"/cheese/12345"`, `"/category/:id"` is an exact match.

Comment: But even in your example, `/:category/:id` is also an exact match?

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture I *did* say that sub-routes and nested `Route` components weren't *quite* the same thing. A nested "catch-all" `path="*"` isn't the same exact thing as a `path="/cheese/*"` route. In my examples both `"/cheese/*"` and `"/cheese/:id"` paths are more specific matches than a `"/:category/:id"` path.